# Acer Aspire E1-422

Tags: bios

My Acer says no bootable drive since I updated the bios to v.2.06 . It only start into a black screen. I can access the bios with F2. There I can see my WDC hard drive and DVD drive, but why it cannot boot to my windows 8.1.

Comment: Reset BIOS settings to defaults and see if it helps. If not, check if you can boot from Windows installation CD/pendrive.

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS contains a checkbox that states 'Enable Legacy' (devices).  Enable this option.

Comment: This is pretty cryptic.  It doesn't explain what "legacy" refers to, where to find it, or what to change it to.  It isn't clear what anybody would do with this information.

Comment: The reason is that you have not looked in the BIOS. There is a rather (completely non-cryptic) checkbox that states 'Enable Legacy' (devices) - so this is a complete answer. It is the BIOS that doesn't have any help info added.